# How do comparison operator in JavaScript work? Comparing string to string, string to number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create simple JS algorithm which accepts 2 variables, compares them to number 4, and gives the answer "A lot" or "Not enough" accordingly. It works fine when I have quotes on number 4, but if I remove them then code starts to work as if there was 0 instead of 4. For example, if I put number 1 for a and number 2 for b the result will be "A lot" even though it must be "Not enough".

Works fine:

```
let a = prompt("Number for a", "1");
let b = prompt("Number for b", "2");
let result = (a+b > "4") ? "A lot" : "Not enough";

alert(result);
```

Works as if there is 0 instead of 4

```
let a = prompt("Number for a", "1");
let b = prompt("Number for b", "2");
let result = (a+b > 4) ? "A lot" : "Not enough";

alert(result);
```

Comment: `"1" + "2"` is `"12"` and `12 > 4`. Your first version doesn't work either.

Comment: Now I see. So I have to transform string into number before I do comparison. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't understand logic of operation `(a + b < 4)`. I thought that since there is operator "<" all the operands will be transformed into numbers, but actually `a + b` summarizes strings and only after that it does the transformation. I know it's lame but this is just 4th day of learning JS. Now I get the importance of prioritization and data types.

This is working correct now. I'll be happy if somebody suggests a better (shorter) solution:

```
let a = prompt("Number for a", "1");
let b = prompt("Number for b", "2");
a = Number(a);
b = Number(b);

result = (a + b > 4) ? 'A lot' : 'Not enough';
alert(result);
```